# Material-UI styling not applied in production but fine in local

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, local, styling, production

So we have a search select component that looks fine in dev, but the second it's pushed up to production it breaks. I've tried moving the styling around or styling in different ways but nothing seems to be working and only breaks the input further. Has anyone got any experience with this issue and how to fix it?

Here is local:

[image]
[image]

And here's what it looks like in production:

[image]
[image]

Here are the components used:

SearchSelect.js

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import NoSsr from "@material-ui/core/NoSsr";

import Async from "react-select/lib/Async";
import debounce from "debounce-promise";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

import { styles, useStyles } from "./Styles";
import * as Components from "./Components";

const comps = { ...Components };
const SearchSelect = ({
  optionsFetcher,
  isMulti,
  minLength,
  delay,
  maxOptions,
  label,
  errors,
  onChange,
  onBlur,
  classes: customClasses,
  value,
  showErrors,
  components,
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [maxReached, setMaxReached] = useState(false);

  const debounced = debounce(val => {
    if (minLength && val.length <= minLength) {
      setMenuIsOpen(false);
      return Promise.resolve([]);
    }
    setMenuIsOpen(true);
    return optionsFetcher(val);
  }, delay);

  const handleChange = (selectedOptions, { action }) => {
    if (maxReached && action !== "remove-value" && action !== "clear") {
      return;
    }

    if (selectedOptions && selectedOptions.length <= maxOptions) {
      setMaxReached(false);
    }

    if (maxOptions && isMulti && action === "select-option") {
      if (selectedOptions.length === Number(maxOptions)) {
        setMaxReached(true);
      }
      setMenuIsOpen(false);
    } else {
      setMenuIsOpen(false);
    }

    onChange(selectedOptions);
  };

  const noOptionsHelper = input => {
    if (input === "") {
      return "Please type to search...";
    }
    return `No options matching "${input}"`;
  };

  const noOptionsMessage = ({ inputValue }) => {
    if (maxReached) {
      return `You can only select ${maxOptions} options.`;
    }
    return noOptionsHelper(inputValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <NoSsr>
        <Async
          classes={classes}
          dropdownIndicator={{
            hasValue: false,
          }}
          inputId="react-select-single"
          TextFieldProps={{
            label,
            InputLabelProps: {
              htmlFor: "react-select-single",
              shrink: "true",
              classes: {
                root: customClasses.cssLabel,
                focused: customClasses.cssFocused,
              },
            },
            InputProps: {
              value: value.label || value,
              classes: {
                root: customClasses.cssOutlinedInput,
                focused: customClasses.cssFocused,
                notchedOutline: customClasses.notchedOutline,
                disabled: customClasses.disabled,
              },
            },
          }}
          error={(showErrors && errors && Boolean(errors.length)) || false}
          helperText={errors}
          placeholder=""
          components={{
            ...components,
            ...comps,
            DropdownIndicator: () => null,
            IndicatorSeparator: () => null,
          }}
          isClearable
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={e => {
            setMenuIsOpen(false);
            onBlur(e);
          }}
          cacheOptions={false}
          loadOptions={val => debounced(val)}
          isMulti={isMulti}
          menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
          closeMenuOnSelect
          blurInputOnSelect={false}
          noOptionsMessage={noOptionsMessage}
          styles={{
            input: () => ({ height: "50px", paddingTop: "13px" }),
          }}
          value={value}
        />
      </NoSsr>
    </div>
  );
};

SearchSelect.defaultProps = {
  isMulti: false,
  minLength: 0,
  delay: 150,
  maxOptions: null,
  showErrors: true,
  errors: null,
  components: {},
};

SearchSelect.propTypes = {
  optionsFetcher: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isMulti: PropTypes.bool,
  minLength: PropTypes.number,
  delay: PropTypes.number,
  maxOptions: PropTypes.number,
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  showErrors: PropTypes.bool,
  errors: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any),
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onBlur: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  classes: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  components: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SearchSelect);
```

Components.js

```
/**
 * All code taken and customised
 * https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/
 * 'react-select' section
 */
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import CancelIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Cancel";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { useStyles } from "./Styles";

export const NoOptionsMessage = ({ selectProps, innerProps, children }) => (
  <Typography
    color="textSecondary"
    className={selectProps.classes.noOptionsMessage}
    {...innerProps}
  >
    {children}
  </Typography>
);
NoOptionsMessage.propTypes = {
  selectProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  innerProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export const inputComponent = ({ inputRef, ...props }) => <div ref={inputRef} {...props} />;
inputComponent.propTypes = { inputRef: PropTypes.string.isRequired };

export const Control = props => {
  const {
    children,
    innerProps,
    innerRef,
    selectProps: { TextFieldProps, error, helperText },
  } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      error={error}
      helperText={helperText}
      {...TextFieldProps}
      InputProps={{
        inputComponent,
        inputProps: {
          className: classes.input,
          ref: innerRef,
          children,
          ...innerProps,
        },
        ...TextFieldProps.InputProps,
      }}
    />
  );
};
Control.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  innerProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  innerRef: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  classes: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  TextFieldProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  helperText: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.array, PropTypes.string]).isRequired,
};

export const Placeholder = props => {
  const { selectProps, innerProps = {}, children } = props;
  return (
    <Typography color="textSecondary" className={selectProps.classes.placeholder} {...innerProps}>
      {children}
    </Typography>
  );
};
Placeholder.propTypes = {
  selectProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  innerProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export const SingleValue = ({ selectProps, innerProps, children }) => (
  <Typography className={selectProps.classes.singleValue} {...innerProps}>
    {children}
  </Typography>
);
SingleValue.propTypes = {
  selectProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  innerProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export const ValueContainer = ({ selectProps, children }) => (
  <div className={selectProps.classes.valueContainer}>{children}</div>
);
ValueContainer.propTypes = {
  selectProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export const MultiValue = ({ children, selectProps, isFocused, removeProps }) => (
  <Chip
    tabIndex={-1}
    label={children}
    className={clsx(selectProps.classes.chip, {
      [selectProps.classes.chipFocused]: isFocused,
    })}
    onDelete={removeProps.onClick}
    deleteIcon={<CancelIcon {...removeProps} />}
  />
);
MultiValue.propTypes = {
  selectProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  isFocused: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  removeProps: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export const Menu = ({ selectProps, innerProps, children }) => (
  <Paper square className={selectProps.classes.paper} {...innerProps}>
    {children}
  </Paper>
);
Menu.propTypes = {
  selectProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  innerProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};
```

Styles.js

```
import { emphasize, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

/**
 * Custom styles to override material UI & react-selects
 * styles
 */
export const styles = {
  cssLabel: {
    color: "#333",
    fontSize: "12px",
    fontWeight: "light",
    zIndex: 3,
  },
  textField: {
    width: "100%",
    margin: "10px 0",
  },

  cssOutlinedInput: {
    "&$cssFocused $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "#333 !important",
      borderRadius: "8px",
      borderWidth: "1.5px",
      zIndex: 2,
    },
  },
  inputTypeSearch: {
    padding: "16px 14px",
  },
  disabled: {
    "&$disabled": {
      cursor: "not-allowed",
      backgroundColor: "#ebebeb",
      borderRadius: "11px",
    },
  },
  cssFocused: {
    "&$cssLabel": {
      color: "#333",
    },
  },
  notchedOutline: {
    border: "1px solid #DBDADA",
    borderRadius: "11px",
    zIndex: 2,
  },
};

/**
 * Code taken from
 * https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/
 * 'react-select' section
 */
export const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    minWidth: 290,
    marginBottom: 12,
    marginTop: 12,
    zIndex: 2,
  },

  input: {
    display: "flex",
    padding: 0,
    height: "auto",
    paddingLeft: "14px",
    zIndex: 2,
    background: "#fff",
  },

  valueContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    flex: 2,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  chip: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0.5, 0.25),
  },
  chipFocused: {
    backgroundColor: emphasize(
      theme.palette.type === "light" ? theme.palette.grey[300] : theme.palette.grey[700],
      0.08,
    ),
  },
  noOptionsMessage: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 2),
  },
  singleValue: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  placeholder: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 14,
    bottom: 11,
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  paper: {
    background: "#F4F4F4",
    border: "none",
    boxShadow: "none",

    position: "absolute",
    top: "30px",
    left: "-4%",

    padding: "50px 0",

    width: "107%",

    zIndex: 1,
  },
  divider: {
    height: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));
```

Comment: Please try to create a working example using https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Make sure node_modules packages version are same in development and production environment.

Comment: @VarunGoel node_modules are exactly the same on both branches

Comment: Please share a sandbox describing the problem, difficult to locate the issue otherwise. https://codesandbox.io/